# AV при использовании EhLib

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, ms-access

При выборе в **TDBLookupComboboxEh** пункта запускается обработчик **OnChange**, который должен загружать в другой **TDBLookupComboboxEh** список по SQL-запросу:

```
begin
  with AccessData.qrySecond, SQL do
  begin
    Clear;
    dblkcbbehSecond.KeyValue := Null;
    if dblkcbbehFirst.KeyValue <> Null then
    begin
      Text := 'SELECT * FROM Second WHERE First='+IntToStr(dblkcbbFirst.KeyValue);
      Open;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Для обычного **TDBLookupCombobox** всё работает чётко (только там вместо **OnChange** используется **OnClick**). А вот при использовании **TDBLookupComboboxEh** (*Eh!!!*) вылетает AV во время закрытия программы.

В чём может быть проблема?

p.s. Delphi 7 + MS Access

Исключение вылетает только при закрытии. При срабатывании (в т.ч. многократном) **OnChange** всё работает как надо, список подгружается.

В принципе, можно оставить только `with` + `Text := ...` + `Open` (т.е. убрать `Clear`, `... := Null` и `if`), всё равно будет ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался!

Добавил `AccessData.conMain.Close` в `FormClose`, ошибка исчезла :)